# How to create new ftp users?

Tags: ftp, openfiler

There's only a default ftp user assigned in openfiler ftp service - openfiler/password.

I've been pulling my hairs out for trying to add users to the ftp server but without any luck.

I have turned on the local LDAP server within Openfiler and add users there and still no luck.

It's for production, so at the end of the day I might have to stick with the default user 'openfiler' and just change its password!

Any helps appreciated.

Been thru [this](https://forums.openfiler.com/viewtopic.php?id=3576) and still no joy.

Answer (score 3):

1.Create group (accounts tab)
2.Create user (accounts tab)
3.Create share (shares tab)
4.Click newly created share and assign permissions for your user / group (share window)
5.Enable FTP for newly created share and user (share window)

You're done :)